# How to Send Aws Iot MQTT message to dynamo db table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, aws-iot

I want to get the mqtt message and put into dynamodb table for that i created a rule and actions for that but i am getting another value when the data is inserted into a dynamo db table . Can you please how can i get the mqtt messsage value to dynamodb table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could provide more information on where and what wrong data you are getting I can help you out with the first part of the question.

> How can I keep MQTT messages in DynamoDB?

You can keep a trigger with a lambda function. Whenever there is a change you can trigger the function to store the data in DynamoDB.

**UPDATE**

You can get more information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-a-serverless-aws-iot-backend-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-dynamodb/). It is explained in detail and solves your exact problem.